# Users get a crash in the application. I can not understand what is the reason

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Error code from Google Play Store

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException () [0x00010] in <24591b779cfa44539866774aba5507c8>:0
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested () [0x00008] in <24591b779cfa44539866774aba5507c8>:0
at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0004f] in <544447f0b401437c85aef83ba01f25c9>:0
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <24591b779cfa44539866774aba5507c8>:0
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <24591b779cfa44539866774aba5507c8>:0
at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0012e] in <544447f0b401437c85aef83ba01f25c9>
at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002cf] in <544447f0b401437c85aef83ba01f25c9>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <d9f87d70a1f64dd39f8fcae9097271df>:0
at Skalka.Cards2Page.ShowCardInfo (System.String ID) [0x000ab] in <ebae4ae5832244dda19b9bbd895cd8aa>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <24591b779cfa44539866774aba5507c8>:0
at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <544447f0b401437c85aef83ba01f25c9>:0
at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <544447f0b401437c85aef83ba01f25c9>:0
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Without looking at the code is really hard to tell. But I will tell you to check your method `ShowCardInfo` at the `Cards2Page` page. It seems a task is being canceled at some point, based on this (ThrowOperationCanceledException) .

Comment: In most cases, when there is a `ThrowOperationCanceledException`, it is being caused from a timeout. Check what the timeout of your request is and is it really hitting it.